# error post dropzoneJs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

I will display existing files on server and then I want grab filename

I have code like this but dosent work for me when I'm click submit
   nothing filename : Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[0]"

```
var adPhotosDropzoneEdit = new Dropzone(".Edit", {
  url: domainAdit,
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 10,
  clickable: '#upload__button__hole__map_edit',
  previewsContainer: '#preview-template-2',
  dictCancelUpload: "",
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  dictRemoveFile: "x",
  acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.JPEG,.JPG,.PNG,.GIF",
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': token
  },

  init: function() {
    var mockFile = {
      name: "20160531101532_asasas.jpeg",
      size: 12345,
      type: 'image/jpeg'
    };
    this.addFile.call(this, mockFile);
    this.options.thumbnail.call(this, mockFile, base_url + "/front/hole/hole_gallery/download.jpg");
  },

  /*init: function () {
                this.on("completemultiple", function (file) {
                  this.removeAllFiles();
                });
              },*/

});
```

Comment: Please provide full code. Thanks.

Comment: @dns_nx I have revision my post, please check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the dropozone default "request Payload" is something like :
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

if "uploadMultiple :true", then it will be like:
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"

The doc is here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-paramName